# How to execute a Linux Cron Job from day x to y on crontab?

Tags: cron, crontab

I found that I can use an hour range by using a slash, for instance, *4-20* to run from 4AM until 8PM.

But what about day range? Can I use something like:

```
* * 5-20 * * CMD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ranges and lists are allowed in all fields. Refer to the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much @jean-karim-bockstael. The manual page really helped.